# Erro na encriptação em c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Olá!
 já tentei analisar o código mas não encontro a resposta

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for StringEncritacao
/// </summary>
namespace Seguranca
{
    public static  class StringEncritacao
    {
        public static string  Encritacao(string sourceData)
        {
            //define a chave e inicializa o valor do vetor
            byte[] key = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
            byte[] iv = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
            try
            {
                //converte o dado para array
                byte[] sourceDataBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sourceData);
                //obter fluxo de memoria
                MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream();
                //apanha o codificador e o fluxo de codificao
                DESCryptoServiceProvider encryptor = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                CryptoStream encryptionStream = new CryptoStream(tempStream, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(key, iv),
                CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            //dado de encriptacao
            encryptionStream.Write(sourceDataBytes, 0,sourceDataBytes.Length);
            encryptionStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            //poe o byte no array
            byte[] encryptedDataBytes = tempStream.GetBuffer();

            //converte o dado de encriptacao para string
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedDataBytes,0,(int)tempStream.Length);
        }
        catch 
        {
            throw new StringEncritacaoExcepion("Incapaz de encriptrar dados");
        }

        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //

    }
    public static string Decriptacao(string sourceData) 
    {
        //define a chave inicializacao  valores vecto
        byte[] key = new byte[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
        byte[] iv = new byte []{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
        try
        {
            //convert o dado para array de byte
            byte[] encryptedDataBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(sourceData);
            //apanha o codigo do fluxo memoria e enche 
            MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedDataBytes, 0, encryptedDataBytes.Length);

            //apanha o decriptador e decriptar o fluxo
            DESCryptoServiceProvider decryptor = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            CryptoStream decryptionStream = new CryptoStream(tempStream, decryptor.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

            //desicriptar
            StreamReader allDataReader = new StreamReader(decryptionStream);
            return allDataReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new StringEncritacaoExcepion("Impossivel desencriptar dados.");
        }

    }
}
```

Quando Executo vem este erro

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Length of the
>   data to decrypt is invalid.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 142:            //grava os dados criptografados no memorystream
>   Line 143:            _cryptoStream.Write(plainByte, 0,
>   plainByte.Length); Line 144:
>   _cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock(); Line 145:            //busca o tamnho dos dados encriptados Line 146:            byte[] cryptoByte =
>   _memoryStream.ToArray();

Comment: Joany, disponibiliza pra gente as suas linhas 142~144, por favor.

Comment: Era mesmo este o erro!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No método de Encriptação você está usando o método CreateDecryptor no lugar de CreateEncryptor.

Troque:

```
CryptoStream encryptionStream = new CryptoStream(tempStream, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(key, iv),
            CryptoStreamMode.Write);
```

por

```
CryptoStream encryptionStream = new CryptoStream(tempStream, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(key, iv),
            CryptoStreamMode.Write);
```